# change the button style in css

Tags: css, ruby, haml

I am new to ruby and I have here a code for a delete button

```
= xs_danger_btn_to "Verwijderen", time_keeper_employee_manager_role_path(@time_keeper, supervisor, manager_role), method: :delete, :btn_class => "custom"
```

I want to change the `xs_danger_btn_to` class to my own things, like color/hover/border ect. in css. How can I do that?

I am running ruby version: 2.3.1p112

Comment: So, what's wrong with your above code? Does it cause an error or some unexpected result? Is `xs_danger_btn_to` a method from a gem or something you wrote yourself? If so, please add a link or show the corresponding implementation.

Comment: That was the problem, I forgot to use ¨link_to¨ en thats why it didnt work

Comment: This should have resulted in a `NoMethodError` saying _"undefined method 'xs_danger_btn_to'"_. Pay some attention to error messages, they are usually quite helpful ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its looks like you are not using the standard syntax for ruby erb. you can try with this:

```
= link_to "Verwijderen", time_keeper_employee_manager_role_path(@time_keeper, supervisor, manager_role), method: :delete, :class => "insertyournewclass"
```

change the 'insertyournewclass' with any class that you want, for example: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' if you are using bootstrap

Comment: I will try! And yes I am using bootstrap v3

Comment: _"not using the standard syntax for ruby erb"_ – the question is tagged `haml`